# Unaccounted lines of code in coverity scan

Tags: static-analysis, coverity

My project has over 150k lines of code according to Coverity Scan, while Cloc reports 30k (which is a lot more reasonable).

I am trying to figure out where those LOCs come from, but failing. How do I get coverity scan to report the actual lines of code? Or report where they come from.

Comment: Try SourceMonitor tool. http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html

Comment: I don't have a windows machine for that. However, counting everything in the source code folder with wc -l $(find .) results in about 50k lines. So Coverity is overreporting source code by a factor of 3.

Answer (score 4):

By default the LOC count includes the system headers pulled in by your application. You may be able to configure component maps to filter these out if it matters enough to you.